# How to search for documents matching X out of Y conditions in Solr, with Sunspot

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, sunspot

I want to be able to run a query equivalent to this ElasticSearch query, using Solr + Sunspot. The example is using Tire, but it's pretty close to the raw query in json:

```
query do
  boolean do
    must do
      boolean minimum_number_should_match: 1 do
        should { term :mod_id, 1 }
        should { term :mod_id, 2 }
        should { term :mod_id, 3 }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my apps, users can tag themselves. Projects are also tagged with the same tags. I want to recommend projects to users, projects that have at least 2 tags in common with a given user for instance.

How would I do that with Sunspot? I only see `minimum_match` for full text search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solr, you can do that with [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) query parser by specifying the `mm` (Minimum should Match) parameter. It works on a multi-valued field `mod_id` like this:

```
http://HOST:PORT/solr/CORE/select?defType=edismax&mm=2&q=mod_id:(1 2 3)
```

That would translate to this query with the lucene query parser:

```
/select?q=(mod_id:(1 AND 2) OR mod_id:(1 AND 3) OR mod_id:(2 AND 3))
```

Hope you can translate that to sunspot.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Well, I don't think sunspot support this directly, but it does allow to get down and dirty and write a lucene query, so that's what I'm gonna try :) Thanks. (ps: I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer)

Comment: If sunspot does not have it, you can add as a default parameter in solr config (or define additional handler)